# Inserting MDDYYYY or MDYYYY format string into date column

Tags: sql, oracle

I am getting dates in .csv files from business team. Sometime they send it in MDDYYYY format and I've used LPAD and TO_DATE to insert this format of string in a DATE column. However, it failed when the file had 3rd of May as 532019. Could you please suggest how to insert this string in date column.

```
INSERT INTO USB.BAS2_AGENCY_TO_RISKRATING_TRAN
(AS_OF_DATE)
VALUES
(TO_DATE(LPAD(5032019,8,0),'MMDDYYYY'));
```

This works for MDDYYYY source values, but not for MDYYYY. I need something which will work for both cases.

Comment: Why are you being sent such badly formatted data? It isn't reasonable to expect a downstream system to cope with garbage. I can see how they might get the first scenario, e.g. from a program stripping leading zeros, but not losing the zero in the middle. If they are constructing the number from date elements then *they* need to pad it properly at that point. I'd talk to whoever is sending you this and get them to fix it.

Comment: Thanks. I've asked them.

Comment: In the example you give, the data simply cannot be parsed (unless there is additional context or undisclosed constraints) because of the ambiguity between the day and the month part. If you strip out the year part, you are left with between 2 and 4 digits to represent both month and day, and there are 3-digit cases such as "112" where it is ambiguous whether that refers to 02-Nov or 12-Jan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be corrected on the front end.  I suggest you get your business team to send their dates in a consistent format.  Its silly to have to deal with dates that come across as 532019, 5032019, or 05032019 - all representing May 3rd 2019.

Answer (score 1):

There is no automatic way to do that, or magic date format model that can cope with it. You'll have to do more manipulation of the source number (as a string), based on its length.

Demo, assuming there are always 6-8 digits:

```
-- CTE for some sample numbers
with cte (num) as (
            select   532019 from dual
  union all select  5032019 from dual
  union all select 05032019 from dual
  union all select 12032018 from dual
  union all select  1232018 from dual
  union all select  1112018 from dual
)
select num,
  case when length(num) = 6 then '0' || substr(num, 1, 1)
                              || '0' || substr(num, 2, 5)
       else to_char(num, 'FM00000000')
  end as full_num,
  to_date(case when length(num) = 6 then '0' || substr(num, 1, 1)
                                             || '0' || substr(num, 2, 5)
               else to_char(num, 'FM00000000')
          end, 'MMDDYYYY') as full_date
from cte;

       NUM FULL_NUM  FULL_DATE 
---------- --------- ----------
    532019 05032019  2019-05-03
   5032019 05032019  2019-05-03
   5032019 05032019  2019-05-03
  12032018 12032018  2018-12-03
   1232018 01232018  2018-01-23
   1112018 01112018  2018-01-11
```

However, this really shouldn't be necessary; and notice the ambiguity, particularly on the last row - is 1112018 supposed to be expanded to 01112018 or 11012018? There is no way for you to know.

I suggest you talk to whoever is sending you this data and get them to fix the process at their end, preferably to always pass unambiguous zero-padded 8-digit number - or even better, unambiguous ANSI date literals instead of numbers.